# PHP Form - bcc mail not sent from email form

Tags: php, email, bcc

hello here is my php code for sending an email, when the mail is sent the address in the bcc section don't receive the email:

```
<?php
$to = "abc@abc.com";
    $subject  = 'Form Submited To ABC Website';
    $headers = "From: online@abc.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "Bcc: info@abc.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
?>
```

the mails are not the rals ones for confidential reasons

Answer (score 0):

PHP mail() syntax is:

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Find bellow code for more understanding.

```
<?php
// multiple recipients
$to  = 'aidan@example.com' . ', '; // note the comma, if you have multiple or else no comma.
$to .= 'wez@example.com';

// subject
$subject = 'Hello';

// message
$message = '<html><body><h2>Testing MSG</h2></body>';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Jiten <Jiten@example.com>, Kelly <hi@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: from_name <from_name@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: cc_email@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: bcc@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```